# Screen brightness always maximum when logoff or restart

Tags: fedora, monitors

I am using Fedora 13 and whenever I Restart or Logoff on my laptop. The screen brightness resets to its maximum value. I am not aware of this problem. Can anyone tell me why this is causing and what is the solution for keeping it's to a constant value at all time?

Comment: Curiously, how do you change the brightness?

Comment: @Tshepang : I change it simply by pressing **Fn+F4 or Fn+F5** Keys. As it's default keys for this and marked symbol for that in my Dell Laptop.

Comment: You need to say what exact laptop model you have, and also what graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the following bugs for possible explanations:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=608900
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/35223
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/464577

It seems that your problem is likely being caused either by gdm or by a bug in gnome-power-manager. If it's the former, then the last bug above points to a [discussion that contains a possible solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9259920) (see the [post by swmail](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9234384&postcount=5)), however, I don't know if it will work in your case (let us know what happens, and we'll work from there ...).

If it's gnome-power-manager causing the problem, it seems that the bug still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the following command at startup:

`echo 0 /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Probably you can have a look at this [link](http://www.pakkatechies.com/2011/12/linux-debian-ubuntu-brightness-setting.html), which provides a workaround till you get a fix from distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service file and in its `[Install]` section write

```
Wants=graphics.target
```

And in 
`[Service]` section write

```
ExecStart=
echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

And it will do the trick.

Comment: Please could you [edit] your post to use formatting, so that you make it clear what someone should write, where. Start each line of code with 4 spaces. Use backticks to `format code inline`.